# How to prove or disprove that there are infinitely many different sequences that start with any finite set of initial terms)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider that we know some finite initial terms of a sequence.

How can we prove or disprove that there can be infinitely many sequences which have these terms as there initial terms?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  After the initial terms, we could have $1,0,0,0,...$; $0,1,0,0,...$, $0,0,1,0,...$, etc.

Comment: Ok now i get it

Comment: Let $a_1,.....,a_k$ but a specific number of finite terms.  Let $\{b_n\}$ be *any* infinite sequence.  I'll take it as a give that you know there are infinitely many such sequences.  Let $\{c_n\}$ be defined as $c_i = a_i$ if $i \le k$ and $c_i = b_{i-k}$ if $i > k$.  So for any $\{b_n\}$ we can define a unique $\{c_n\}$.  So there are infinitely many such sequences.

Comment: Yes i got it now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinitely many sequences which have given finitely many initial terms.

For example, after the initial terms we could have $1,0,0,0,...; 0,1,0,0,...; 0,0,1,0,...; $ etc.

(So if you are given the first few terms of a sequence (e.g., $1,2, 4, 8, 16, 32$),

you can't say what the rest of the terms of the sequence are, without further information.)